# CORS error while performing stripe checkout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am working on a stripe checkout project but got stuck when I was not able to redirect to the stripe checkout page because of the cors error. My react frontend is running at localhost 3000 and express backend at localhost 5000. Here is how I am setting headers and using cors in my server.js :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL
    }))
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'sameorigin');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, multipart/form-data");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "HEAD,GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT");
    next();
  });
```

Here is my stripe.route.js :

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const Stripe = require('./../controllers/stripe.controller');

router.post('/checkout' , async(req,res) => {
    const product = req.body.body;
    console.log(product);
    try
    {
    const session = Stripe.createCheckoutSession(product)

    return res.send(session)
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400)
        return res.send({
            error: {
                message: e.message
            }
        })
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

Here is my stripe.controller.js:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

const createCheckoutSession = async(plan) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: `http://localhost:3000/success`,
  cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/fail`,
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [
    {price: plan, quantity: 1},
  ],
  mode: 'subscription',
});
return session;
}

module.exports = {
  createCheckoutSession
}
```

Here is my react fronend page :

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { isAuth } from "../helpers/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from "./Pricing.module.scss";
export const Pricing = () => {
  const buttonValue = useRef();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const setBtnValue = (e) => {  
    buttonValue.current = e.target.value;
  };
  const checkoutHandler = async (e) => {
    const btnValue = buttonValue.current;
    console.log(btnValue);
      const res = await axios
     .post( 'http://localhost:5000/api/checkout' , {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: 
        btnValue,
    })
    const url = res.url
    window.location.href = url
      
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h2 className={styles.heading}>Choose</h2>
      <div className={styles.priceRow}>
        <div className={styles.priceCol}>
          <p>Starter</p>
          <h3>
            50$ <span> / month</span>
          </h3>
          <ul>
            <li>1 Website</li>
            <li>10 GB Disk Space</li>
            <li>Free Email Address</li>
            <li>No SSL certificate</li>
            <li>Limited Support</li>
          </ul>
          <form onSubmit={checkoutHandler}>
            <button
              value="price_1"
              type="submit"
              className="btn"
              name="product"
              onClick={setBtnValue}
            >
              Upgrade Now
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share the full CORS error please?

Comment: indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its samesite attribute

Comment: When I request the stripe checkout page , I see in network tab that no headers are setting which I have used in server.js . Also I succesfully created the session and got the session id , when I checked by logging the session .

Comment: You really shouldn't need to set all the headers. This seems like an issue between your frontend and Node server, and not the Stripe API.

Comment: It can be a cross domain issue and also what headers should I remove from server.js

Comment: Have you looked at the Stripe Checkout [quickstart guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart)? There's a full example for a React frontend with a Node.js server. There's no CORS configuration required there.

Comment: Yeah I already studied that .

Comment: Look I am receiving this type of object on consoling session from stripe.route.js https://pastebin.com/TsDKH3PD , so how should I send it from route.js and access it in my frontend

Comment: You make the POST request with `credentials: 'same-origin'`, but it is a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have another idea. You can try to send back generated url from Stripe `session.url` and then from frontend you can easily open this url by calling `window.location.href=url`.

It's not solving the redirection issue with backend but that solution is also correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).